# Trying to find the name of this "slidable UIView"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Anyone know what the control is called to achieve the functionality shown here in the iOS Stocks app?

I've been searching Google for things like 'Slidable UIView' but can't find anything!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQRrN.png]

Comment: You mean the graph, or the thing with the dots at the bottom that allows you to switch between pages, that just happens to contain a graph?

Comment: I mean the switch between pages control :) Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the graph, there's no native component for that, but you can use an external library, for example CorePlot:

https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

If you mean the scroll view with pages, it's just a UIScrollView with a content size of several pages and a UIPageController attached.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was infact talking about the UIPageController/UIScrollView!

Answer (score 3):

Sliding View -> Have a look at this:https://github.com/dickverbunt/DVSlideViewController.

Besides that you need to have pageControl:https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/smpagecontrol

This is how the dots appear in the image.

Plotting Graph -> Have a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Tutorial for PageControl with ScrollView: http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.sg/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html

Comment: I'd mark this as correct. It's using the stock PageControl element.